# Better way to update the HTML <main> content?

Tags: jquery, html, material-design

I am building a mobile website using google's material design resources(sidebar, header, etc).
The problem is that I have to load the entire template every time I load a new html file, which means that I need to include the sidebar, header, and so on every html file. I would like to load only the `main` tag content instead.

Any idea of the best way to do this? I am actually using only jquery, but I am not discarding to use another library.

Comment: Use ajax. Load content from other pages in the main div. have a look at $.post, $.get and $.ajax

Comment: Thanks Lelio.
I am avoiding this because html content is pretty large to do a jquery append() or html(). I would like to do it in a "cleaner" way.

Comment: You can use iframes.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong. Ajax can handle large amount of data. I am not speaking about append. Just fyi... You are loading just a subset of the entire page. How much time does it take to load the entire page? Anyway feel free to use a different way from almost all the websites around...